# Are there any maps which preserve addition and multiplication over Matrics?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I don't know whether the title is correct, cause English is not my native language. 
What I mean is:
Suppose there is a function, say $f$, which maps Matrix $A$ into Matrix $A'$, and satisfies
$$f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B)$$
This is what I mean by saying preserving addition.
Of course, something like $f(A)=QA$ is a solution, but I prefer non-linear solutions.
And preserving multiplication means 
$$f(AB)=f(A)f(B)$$

Are there any examples of this kind of mapping, which preserve addition or multiplication or both?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You *prefer non-linear solutions*, but your preconditions to me seem to indicate at least $\cal Q$ linearity.

Answer (score 3):

I am answering the *"both"* part of the question.

You are talking of the algebra endomorphisms of the algebra of matrices with coeffients in a field. (I assume you require also linearity over the field in question, see the comment by @VenWox.) Now [the algebra of matrices over a field is a simple ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_ring#Structure), so every nonzero endomorphism is injective, and thus surjective by dimension arguments.

So it boils down to the automorphisms. It is a consequence of the [Skolem-Noether theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%E2%80%93Noether_theorem) that each of these automorphisms $\varphi$ is inner, that is, of the form
$$
\varphi : A \mapsto g^{-1} A g,
$$
for some invertibile matrix $g$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @VenWox, you're very welcome!